# Center Multiple (4) Views Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 views in my view controller that look like this:

```
self.underConstruction.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 125, width: 250, height: 250)

self.scheduleJobs.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 125, width: 250, height: 250)

self.withoutSchedule.frame = CGRect(x: 500, y: 125, width: 250, height: 250)

self.withoutPM.frame = CGRect(x: 750, y: 125, width: 250, height: 250)


self.view.addSubview(self.underConstruction)

self.view.addSubview(self.scheduleJobs)

self.view.addSubview(self.withoutSchedule)

self.view.addSubview(self.withoutPM)
```

I want these 4 views to be centred on the view controller and all of them next to each other and when the device goes to portrait have the views centered and below each other. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: A horizontal stack in landscape and a vertical stack in portrait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let st  = UIStackView() 
    let v1  = UIView()
    let v2  = UIView()
    let v3  = UIView()
    let v4  = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v1.backgroundColor = .red
        v2.backgroundColor = .gray
        v3.backgroundColor = .green
        v4.backgroundColor = .blue

        v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        st.axis = .vertical

        st.distribution = .fillEqually

        st.alignment = .center

        view.addSubview(st)

        st.addArrangedSubview(v1)

        st.addArrangedSubview(v2)

        st.addArrangedSubview(v3)

        st.addArrangedSubview(v4)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),

            st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),

            st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor,constant:20),

            st.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),

            v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.heightAnchor),

            v2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v2.heightAnchor),

            v3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v3.heightAnchor),

            v4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v4.heightAnchor),

        ])

    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
           st.axis = .horizontal
        } else {
           st.axis = .vertical
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let st  = UIStackView()
    let st1 = UIStackView()
    let st2 = UIStackView()

    let v1  = UIView()
    let v2  = UIView()
    let v3  = UIView()
    let v4  = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v1.backgroundColor = .red
        v2.backgroundColor = .gray
        v3.backgroundColor = .green
        v4.backgroundColor = .blue



        v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        st.axis = .vertical

        st1.axis = .horizontal

        st2.axis = .horizontal

        st.distribution = .fillEqually

        st.alignment = .center

        view.addSubview(st)

        st.addArrangedSubview(st1)

        st.addArrangedSubview(st2)

        st1.addArrangedSubview(v1)

        st1.addArrangedSubview(v2)

        st2.addArrangedSubview(v3)

        st2.addArrangedSubview(v4)

        st1.distribution = .fillEqually

        st2.distribution = .fillEqually

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),

            st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),

            st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor,constant:20),

            st.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),

            v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.heightAnchor),

            v2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v2.heightAnchor),

            v3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v3.heightAnchor),

            v4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v4.heightAnchor),


        ])

    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
           st.axis = .horizontal
           st1.axis = .vertical
           st2.axis = .vertical
        } else {
           st.axis = .vertical
            st1.axis = .horizontal 
            st2.axis = .horizontal
        }

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This works perfectly....for extra credit, instead of have one below another, how would I get two per a row in portrait?

Comment: Thank you very much, this works nicely....however when I am in portrait my views are massive. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UIStackView` with a horizontal axis in landscape and a vertical axis in portrait.

Listen for orientation changes and set the `.axis` property of the stack view accordingly.

Comment: Example of this?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented paulvs's solution using three views (four was too big for the iPad). Here's the result. In portrait:

[image]

In landscape:

[image]

The extra black view is to prove to you that the app really did rotate. In addition to working just fine, the views perform a delightful animation as the rotation takes place and they rearrange themselves.

As paulvs suggested, the three views are in a stack view. They each have width and height constraints. The stack view has centerX and centerY constraints, with fill distribution and fill alignment. The only code looks like this:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, 
    with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (con) in
            if size.width > size.height {
                self.stackView.axis = .horizontal
            } else {
                self.stackView.axis = .vertical
        }
    })
}
```